# Multiple control statements and keeping to 80 character lines in python

Tags: python

When trying to adhere to PEP8 it is sometimes very difficult to keep within the 80 character limit. For example:

```
for i in range(10):
    for k in range(10):
        if k < 5:
            try:
                with line as open(file):
                    if line.blah in text:
                        dosomethingwithnospaceleft(bla,
                                                   bla,
                                                   )
```

My point is that the 80 character limit sometimes gets a bit ridiculous and in some ways hard to read. What was the reasoning behind this formatting? Isn't it an outdated standard for the majority of people who use aren't using editors > 20 years old.

Comment: I agree, and I ignore the line-length limit in my coding.  If you don't like it, just don't abide by it.

Answer (score 6):

Limiting line length is good because it generally makes text more readable. Also, indenting so many levels is generally a sign that you should factor something out into a different function.

You might also want to continue early, saving you an indentation level (`if k >= 5: continue`, `if line.blah not in text: continue`).

Comment: That's a good idea of breaking out functionality, but in general with all your class->def->for->for->if-> you're losing at least 24 characters off the bat. Then for functions and strings with long names or list comprehensions you are working with very limited space. The example I was giving was trivial but that is a cool trick for saving indentation using continues.

Answer (score 0):

From  [PEP-008](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length)

> Maximum Line Length
>
> Limit all lines to a maximum of 79 characters.
>
> There are still many devices around that are limited to 80 character
>   lines; plus, limiting windows to 80 characters makes it possible to
>   have several windows side-by-side. The default wrapping on such
>   devices disrupts the visual structure of the code, making it more
>   difficult to understand. Therefore, please limit all lines to a
>   maximum of 79 characters. For flowing long blocks of text (docstrings
>   or comments), limiting the length to 72 characters is recommended.
>
> The preferred way of wrapping long lines is by using Python's implied
>   line continuation inside parentheses, brackets and braces. Long lines
>   can be broken over multiple lines by wrapping expressions in
>   parentheses. These should be used in preference to using a backslash
>   for line continuation. Make sure to indent the continued line
>   appropriately. The preferred place to break around a binary operator
>   is after the operator, not before it. Some examples:

```
class Rectangle(Blob):

    def __init__(self, width, height,
                 color='black', emphasis=None, highlight=0):
        if (width == 0 and height == 0 and
            color == 'red' and emphasis == 'strong' or
            highlight > 100):
            raise ValueError("sorry, you lose")
        if width == 0 and height == 0 and (color == 'red' or
                                           emphasis is None):
            raise ValueError("I don't think so -- values are %s, %s" %
                             (width, height))
        Blob.__init__(self, width, height,
                      color, emphasis, highlight)
```